# Limite FormulaArray

Tags: vba, excel-vba

```
Range("B11").Select
Dim Rmts As String
Dim Busca As String

Rmts = "C:\Users\Treinamento\Desktop\Trabalho em vba\BC\[Relacionamentos.xlsx]Matriz_Trein_Obrigatórios"
Busca = "'!R8C6:R394C34=Busca!R8C2,ROW('"

Range("B11:B450").FormulaArray = _
"=IFERROR(INDEX('" & Rmts & _
"'!R8C3:R394C34,SMALL(IF('" & Rmts & _
Busca & Rmts & "'!R8C6:R394)-7),ROW(R[-10]C[-1])),1),"""")"
```

Estou tentando fazer uma fórmula de índice funcionar no VBA, porém a FormulaArray não aceita incluir toda a linha da fórmula. Já vi que não poderia ultrapassar mais de 255 caracteres, por isso dividi e reduzi ao máximo, porém ainda assim não aceita.

Poderia me dizer onde estou errando, ou se realmente não tem como fazer ela funcionar com tantos caracteres?

Muito Obrigado.

Comment: O caminho para o arquivo é muito long e repete-se 3 vezes. Uma forma que eu vejo de reduzir isso é mapear a pasta numa drive como algo como `SUBST w:  C:\Users\Treinamento\Desktop\Trabalho em vba\BC\ `. A partir desse ponto consegue chegar à pasta fazendo apenas w:\, logo a sua variavel `Rmts` passaria a ficar apenas `Rmts = "w:\[Relacionamentos.xlsx]Matriz_Trein_Obrigatórios"`. Agora é possível que existam outras soluções mais limpas que eu desconheça.

Comment: Posso tentar, porém eu fico em dúvida em relação a substituição. Mesmo quando tentei fazer a substituição, trocando ou usando um replace, ainda não consigo fazer dar certo. Aliás, eu tentei incluir o arquivo uma sheet para não ter que buscar ele separado, porém ainda assim não funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Além do que o @Isac falou de diminuir o tamanho do caminho `Rmts` para conseguir 255 caracteres.

Uma substituição pode ser realizada da seguinte forma:

1. Uma string qualquer é inserida no FormulaArray no lugar de Rmts
2. Substituir esta string pelo caminho desejado

No exemplo a string "temp" será usada, em que uma planilha de nome temp é criada temporariamente para não gerar erros, depois é excluída.

#### Código

```
Dim Rmts As String
Dim Busca As String
Dim destino As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet, temp As Worksheet

Set temp = Worksheets.Add
temp.Name = "temp"
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1")
Set destino = ws.Range("B11:B450")
With destino
    Rmts = "C:\Users\Treinamento\Desktop\Trabalho em vba\BC\[Relacionamentos.xlsx]Matriz_Trein_Obrigatórios"
    Busca = "'!R8C6:R394C34=Busca!R8C2,ROW('"
    .FormulaArray = _
                  "=IFERROR(INDEX('temp" & _
                  "'!R8C3:R394C34,SMALL(IF('" & "temp" & _
                  Busca & "temp" & "'!R8C6:R394)-7),ROW(R[-10]C[-1])),1),"""")"
    .Replace "temp", Rmts, xlPart
End With
temp.Delete
```